# Is there a way to quickly copy games between PS Vita memory cards?

Tags: ps-vita

I've spent 5 hours last night downloading *Atelier Totori Plus* (and thus why I hate digital distribution), obviously I don't want to go though that again (with the constant fear that it's going to cut out), so I'm wondering if there is a way to transfer my game between memory cards.

I have a 16 GB card which I may need to upgrade if this stupid trend to have digital downloads and no physical copy continues, as I would have gladly brought *Atelier Totori Plus* physically if it was available (and had the bonus content).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Content Manager to back up the data to a PC or PS3 and then using the same tool, restore the data onto your new memory card.

Comment: oh cool, i only get the Vita yesterday and was going to see how this Content Manager worked tonight after work since it seems to be how i'll upload my images, guess when i get back home tonight i'm going to run a backup and store it on both my main harddrive and the backup before i do anything else